# Kohana select field misbehaves when &amp; present

Tags: kohana

I have a Kohana select field whose output looks like this:

```
<select id="section" name="section">
    <option value="">please choose</option>
    <option value="Board of Directors">Board of Directors</option>
    <option value="Central Office &amp; Staff">Central Office &amp; Staff</option>
    <option value="Executive Committee">Executive Committee</option>
</select>
```

Notice that the section option contains an `&amp;`. When I have a record whose `section` value is `Central Ofice & Staff`, my select field just reads "please choose" instead of having `Central Office & Staff` selected. This happens even when I change `Central Office & Staff` to `Central Office &amp; Staff` in an effort to make the fields match.

It seems like this must be a common problem. How to I make the select field behave properly?

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
<option value="Central Office & Staff">Central Office &amp; Staff</option>
```

This is because `&amp;` works only for HTML, so the value from URL/DB will not match.
By the way - this would not happen if you used `Form::select` helper ;)

Comment: It seems to me that that would work. Unfortunately it looks like Kohana is automatically escaping all entities no matter what I feed into the select field. Maybe I should look into `Form::select`.

Comment: The select field is being created via `$form->addField('section', 'select', array(...`. I don't know if that's just another way of doing the same thing or not. (I don't really use Kohana.)

Comment: You're probably using 3rd party module for creating forms. Try to look for an update or extend the module method addField and correct it.